# Averaging elements of a list of vectors in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, lapply

I have a list of 3 vectors, `[[1]]`, `[[2]]`, and `[[3]]`. I was wondering how to merge `[[2]]` and `[[3]]` into just `[[2]]` by taking the `mean` of `[[2]]` and `[[3]]` **IF** the same element (here `Bit.KnoB`) appears in both `[[2]]` and `[[3]]`.

My desired output is also shown below.

```
d = list(c(Bit.KnoA = 4, Bit.KnoB = 1, Bit.KnoC = 2, Ellis.etal =4, Mubarak=5, SheenA=6, 
               Shin.Ellis=7 , Sun = 8), 

        c(Bit.KnoA = 6, Bit.KnoB = 3, Bit.KnoC = 4, Ellis.etal =1, Mubarak=2, SheenA=1,  
              Shin.Ellis=2 , Sun = 1),

       c(Bit.KnoB = 2) )
```

**Desired output**:

```
d = list(c(Bit.KnoA = 4, Bit.KnoB = 1, Bit.KnoC = 2, Ellis.etal =4, Mubarak=5, SheenA=6, 
               Shin.Ellis=7 , Sun = 8), 

        c(Bit.KnoA = 6, Bit.KnoB = 2.5, Bit.KnoC = 4, Ellis.etal =1, Mubarak=2, SheenA=1,  
              Shin.Ellis=2 , Sun = 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to subset the `list` with the concerned elements, `stack` it to a single data.frame, `aggregate` to get the `mean` and then append with the first element from the 'd'

```
out1 <- aggregate(values ~ ind, do.call(rbind, 
      lapply(d[intersect(seq_along(d), 2:3)],
            stack)) ,mean, na.rm = TRUE)
list(d[[1]], setNames(out1$values, out1$ind))
#[[1]]
#  Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB   Bit.KnoC Ellis.etal    Mubarak     SheenA Shin.Ellis        Sun 
#         4          1          2          4          5          6          7          8 

#[[2]]
#  Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB   Bit.KnoC Ellis.etal    Mubarak     SheenA Shin.Ellis        Sun 
#       6.0        2.5        4.0        1.0        2.0        1.0        2.0        1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

`tapply` is also handy when working on the names:

```
pt <- unlist(d[2:3])
d[[2]] <- tapply(pt, names(pt), FUN=mean)
d[[3]] <- NULL
d
#[[1]]
#  Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB   Bit.KnoC Ellis.etal    Mubarak     SheenA Shin.Ellis        Sun 
#         4          1          2          4          5          6          7          8 
#
#[[2]]
#  Bit.KnoA   Bit.KnoB   Bit.KnoC Ellis.etal    Mubarak     SheenA Shin.Ellis        Sun 
#       6.0        2.5        4.0        1.0        2.0        1.0        2.0        1.0
```